# What should I do when using apache licensed library in my github project

Tags: apache-2.0, license

I am maintaining a Github project which is owned by our company.  It's a sample for demonstrating how to use the software sold by our company.

My question is, if I want to modify code of another Github project under Apache license 2.0 and use it in my project, what should I do in my obligation? (this Apache licensed software has a block for LICENSE statement but doesn't have a block for NOTICE)

I have done some researches but can't understand very well because there are many terms and English is not my first language.
In my understanding, I need to add a NOTICE file in root directory to let people know I use this software.
Do I need to specify which files are modified or copied from this Apache licensed software project(they are located in three different  folders)?

Here is what I plan to do(ExoPlayer for example), I will add a NOTICE file in root directory:

```
MyProject
Copyright (c) 2020 OurCompany

This project uses the modified code from this project:

================================================
ExoPlayer
Licensed under the Apache License Version 2.0
================================================
```

Do I do it right?
I will appreciate for the answers and thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need a Notice file for ASL compatible dependencies, only for things with surprising (but still FLOSS) license. So if the library you used did not have a NOTICE file or if it only applies to parts you don't redistribute, you can skip it (but you still need to keep the copyright and change notices).